# Having trouble with color code in batch file

Tags: batch-file, vt100

I'm trying to only have ffmpeg progress to be colored, but for some reason when I terminate or go full-screen this monstrosity occurs:
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW9iu.png)

```
@echo off
@echo off
title Stream Recorder
cls
:start
set message=Stream Recorder
echo %message%
echo(
echo [32m1. Chrome [0m
echo [34m2. Edge [0m
echo [33m3. Firefox [0m
echo [31m4. Opera [0m
echo [1;31m5. Vivaldi [0m
:choice
set choice=
set /p "choice=* Pick your browser (between 1-5): "
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto chrome
echo "%choice%" is not valid, try again.
ECHO.
goto choice

:chrome
:url
echo(
set /p "address=* M3U8 Url: "
For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%curl.exe -s -o NUL "%address%" -w "%%{http_code}\n"') Do Set "response=%%G"
echo %response%
IF %response% == 200 (
    ECHO [32mURL check was successful.[m &goto :username
) ELSE (
    ECHO [31mURL is not valid, try again.[m &goto :url
)
:username
set /p "filename=* Streamer Name: "
echo(
set message=* Recording:
echo [0m%message%[42;1m
ffmpeg -v warning -hide_banner -stats -user_agent "" -i "%address%" -c copy "%~dp0/%filename%_%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~-4%_%time:~-11,2%-%time:~-8,2%-%time:~-5,2%.mp4"
pause
```

Also, would be helpful if my code needs some cleaning up.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by terminate, because surely when you've terminated it, there will be noting to see! It would also help if you explain exactly what you are doing with the window, why are you maximizing/resizing it in the GUI? Why did you not predefine the window size and/or buffer as needed, (either in the properties for the shortcut to the batch file, if launched that way, or in the batch file itself)? Please understand that we need to know exactly what you are doing and why, in order to properly reproduce your problem, and to then assist you with it.

Comment: As Compo has stated, some explanation is needed which I feel Compo has stated quite well in his comment. Please post a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: @Compo Basically when I terminate batch job it will turn green as well instead of being limited to ffmpeg progress as you can see [link](https://i.imgur.com/1pvfW7s.png)

Comment: @LaryDavid, please reread my comment, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

That last echo is the problem:

> `echo` <kbd>*Escape*</kbd>`[0m%message%`<kbd>*Escape*</kbd>`[42;1m`

The first <kbd>*Escape*</kbd> chunk turns ***off*** color and bold, while the second turns color and bold ***on***.

To fix the problem, you need (at least)

> `echo` <kbd>*Escape*</kbd>`[0m`

before the `pause`.  But that may not be enough, because `ffmpeg` is printing to the terminal (presumably) without modifying colors.  If it happens to clear the current line or to the end of the display, most terminals (supporting [*back color erase*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bce_mismatches)) will fill the cleared area with the current color.

Perhaps you don't want `ffmpeg` to have that opportunity.